# How to migrate a site collection and the related term store toward another farm?

Tags: managed-metadata, term-store, term-set

I am using SP2013 on-premise standard edition. In a site collection we have built a local term set group with 100+ termsets. We are going to use Backup-SPSite & Restore-SPSite to copy this site collection to another SP2013 farm. As far as I understand, the local term set group is not saved in the content DB. It is saved in managed metadata DB.

How should I copy the term set group towards the new farm? I cannot directly backup/restore the managed metadata DB because the destination DB contains termsets from other site collections and we should not override it. Also we don't have DB access.

If I export the termsets into CSV and import to new environment, the terms' GUID will be changed. Then I have to go over every library and list to fix the 100+ managed metadata column.

May I have your advice on this situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I successfully did it by following this blog post:

Source SP Farm - Windows Azure SharePoint Server 2013 VM.

Destination SP Farm - SharePoint Server 2013 VM.

http://blog.kuppens-switsers.net/sharepoint/migrate-managed-metadata-between-farms/?subscribe=success#blog_subscription-3

Note: First migrate term store and then Backup/Restore site collection.

Finally Change site collection administrators of restored site collection from Central Administration (CA).

Here are detailed steps:

## http://blog.kuppens-switsers.net/sharepoint/migrate-managed-metadata-between-farms/

## Step 1 - Export Term Store script

```
$mmsApplication = Get-SPServiceApplication | ? {$_.TypeName -eq "Managed Metadata Service"}
$mmsProxy = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | ? {$_.TypeName -eq "Managed Metadata Service Connection"}
Export-SPMetadataWebServicePartitionData $mmsApplication.Id -ServiceProxy $mmsProxy -Path "C:\MMS\mmsdata.cab"
```

## Step 2 - Import script

```
$mmsApplication = Get-SPServiceApplication | ? {$_.TypeName -eq "Managed Metadata Service"}
$mmsProxy = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | ? {$_.TypeName -eq "Managed Metadata Service Connection"}
Import-SPMetadataWebServicePartitionData $mmsApplication.Id -ServiceProxy $mmsProxy -Path "C:\MMS\mmsdata.cab" -OverwriteExisting
```

## Step 3 - Backup site

```
Backup-SPSite -Identity "http://sp2103dev/sites/abc/" -Path "C:\MMS\sitetoarchive.bak"
```

## Step 4 - Restore site

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity "http://sp2013/sites/xyz" -Path "C:\MMS\sitetoarchive.bak" -force
```

## Step 5 - Note

After site restore we need to change site collection administrator(s) in Central Admin so that these users can access the site.

Answer (score 1):

Go for the export and import of the term set and then fix the existing items with a PowerShell script. The script should lookup the term in the term store given the text of an old term. Then it should assign the correct term with a new id. Hope it does make sense. I have a PowerShell script for that and if noone else posts an answer, I will upload it here once I get access to it (later in the day).

Comment: Can you find the script? Thank you for update.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is using powershell script to export and import the term set as Paul mentioned.

Here are script.

**To Export**

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
 $metadataApp= Get-SpServiceApplication | ? {$_.TypeName -eq "Managed Metadata Service"}
 $mmsAppId = $metadataApp.Id

 $mmsproxy = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | ?{$_.TypeName -eq "Managed Metadata Service Connection"}
 Export-SPMetadataWebServicePartitionData -Identity $mmsAppId -ServiceProxy $mmsproxy -Path "C:\Users\Desktop\MMD.cab”
```

**To Import**

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
 $metadataApp= Get-SpServiceApplication | ? {$_.TypeName -eq "Managed Metadata Service"}
 $mmsAppId = $metadataApp.Id

 $mmsproxy = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | ?{$_.TypeName -eq "Managed Metadata Service Connection"}

Import-SPMetadataWebServicePartitionData -Identity $mmsAppId -ServiceProxy $mmsproxy -Path "//SharedPath/Users/Desktop/MMD.cab" -OverwriteExisting;
```

Source: [Migrating Managed Metadata Term Stores in SharePoint Server across Farms](http://www.sharepoint-zone.com/2014/01/importing-and-exporting-managed.html)

Comment: https://sharepointtales.wordpress.com/ said "Importing will completely overwrite your existing term store". So am I correct that above script will discard destination farm's existing term sets? Can I just "append" my termsets to destination MMS?